# accessing methods outside the constructor using javascript?

Tags: javascript

Im trying to access a method outside of the constructor by using `this` for example:

```
var Garage = function(location){
    this.someRandomMethod = function(){
      alert("I am a method");
    }

    // car object
    var Car = function(make,model){
      this.model = model;
      this.make  = make;

      var accessRandom = function(){
         this.someRandomMethod(); // the problem!
       }
    }
}
```

But I am getting function is not defined on the console.

Comment: `this` is not inherited among nested functions.

Comment: `console.log(this);`

Comment: See [How to access the correct `this` / context inside a callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/218196) . However, `Car` should probably not be defined inside `Garage` anyway.

Comment: sorry for asking blimey!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `this` is referring to the `Car`, not the `Garage`. Try assigning the outer `this` to a variable:

```
var Garage = function(location){
    this.someRandomMethod = function(){
      alert("I am a method");
    }

    var garage = this;

    // car object
    var Car = function(make,model){
      this.model = model;
      this.make  = make;

      var accessRandom = function(){
         garage.someRandomMethod();
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: *"The `this` is referring to the `Car`"* I assume you mean instance of `Car` (not the function `Car`), but even then, we don't know that. We don't know how `accessRandom` is called.